# Control how uncaught exceptions are logged on exit in Python?

Tags: python

I've got the following python program:

```py
import logging

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # configure logger to write logs in json format, and put exception traceback on "exception" field

    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    logger.info("worker started")

    try:
        # do some worker stuff

        logger.info("worker finished successfully")

    except Exception:
        logger.exception("unknown error occurred")
        # what to do here?
```

I want to be able to write all logs in json format so I can easily search through them in CloudWatch, therefore I am configuring my logger with a custom formatter to do this. When an exception is raised, I want to control how that is logged as well so it has all of the same fields as the other logs, and the traceback doesn't spill across cloudwatch as a bunch of separate events. However, I also need this program to exit with an error status when this happens.

I'm aware of a few choices. The following logs correctly, but since the exception is handled it exits as though all went well:

```py
except Exception:
    logger.exception("unknown error occurred")
```

This next one exits correctly and will log the exception once the way I want, but then a second time in the ugly way, where it doesn't follow my formatting and comes out as multiple lines in ECS:

```py
except Exception:
    logger.exception("unknown error occurred")
    raise
```

This gets the closest, but I see use of `sys.exit(1)` discouraged and I don't love the indirection of another exception. For example, debugging in VS Code will handily take you to the last line in the traceback if your program exits on an exception, but this is ruined if you use `sys.exit(1)` in this way (you'll always go to the sys.exit() line instead of the location of the real exception):

```py
except Exception:
    logger.exception("unknown error occurred")
    sys.exit(1)
```

Is there a "right" way to just directly exit on the *real* exception while also *only* logging the traceback how I want though my configured logger?

Comment: Where do you see `sys.exit(1)` being discouraged? Don't write your code to appease the debugger. (Frankly, you *should* use `sys.exit` where possible rather than letting your code terminate with an uncaught exception.)

Comment: @chepner I think I've just seen people suggest you raise a descriptive exception over using sys.exit() whenever possible. I _have_ such a descriptive exception already here, so it feels kind of pointless and extra to raise another exception (SystemExit). The fact that this confuses my debugger isn't a problem per se, but just seems like a symptom of me not doing this correctly (if this messes up the debugger, what else won't work as expected?). I'd really love to just have full control over all logging, and tell python how to log unhandled exceptions the same as my normal logs.

Comment: `sys.exit` raises a `SystemExit` exception. A regular implementation treats that as a signal to, well, exit; the debugger seems to treat it like any other exception.